# optimized bsort in C

Tags: c, sorting, optimization, bubble-sort

I was looking at wikipedia's bsort page and I tried to implement the two [optimized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Pseudocode_implementation) versions that are in pseudo code in C, but the results don't seem to add up. Here's my code:

Implementation 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SWAP(a, b) (a ^= b ^= a ^= b)

void tbsort(int a[], int n)
{
        int i, swapped;

        do {
            swapped = 0;
            for (i = 1; i <= n - 1; i++) {
                    if (a[i - 1] > a[i]) {
                            SWAP(a[i - 1], a[i]);
                            swapped = 1;
                    } 
            }
            n -= 1;
        } while (!swapped);

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            printf("%d ->", a[i]);
        putchar('\n');
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int a[10] = { 20, 22, 13, 0, 10, 11, 12, 13, 9, 3};

        tbsort(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(int));


        return 0;
}
```

Implementation 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define SWAP(a, b) (a ^= b ^= a ^=b)

void tbsort(int a[], int n)
{
        do {
            int i, newn = 0;
        
            for (i = 1; i <= n-1; i++) {
                if (a[i-1] > a[i]) {
                    SWAP(a[i-1], a[i]);
                    newn = i;
                }
            }
            n = newn;
        } while (!n);

        {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            printf("%d ->", a[i]);
        putchar('\n');
        }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int a[10] = { 20, 22, 13, 0, 10, 11, 12, 13, 9, 3};

        tbsort(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(int));

        return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

> implementation1: 20 ->0 ->0 ->0 ->0 ->0 ->0 ->0 ->0 ->22 ->
>
> implementation2: 20 ->0 ->0 ->0 ->0 ->0 ->0 ->0 ->0 ->22 ->

Could you help me understand what could be wrong?

Comment: `!swapped` --> `swapped`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. The macro `SWAP` looks cool, however you shall never use it like that again. Let's try some code first:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main(int argc, char **argv)
   {
       #define SWAP(a, b) (a ^= b ^= a ^= b)

       int x[] = { 1, 2, };
       SWAP(x[0], x[1]);
       printf("%d %d\n", x[0], x[1]);

       int a = 1;
       int b = 2;
       SWAP(a, b);
       printf("%d %d\n", a, b);

       return 0;
   }
   ```

   I guess you may amazingly find it generate outputs unexpected. The reason is that your `SWAP` actually relies on specific undefined behaviors: the sequence of fetching values from memory and also writing back to memory (however in this case it's because of the manner of fetching values) on statements like `a ^= b ^= c ^= d;`.
   To solve this you just need something like:

   ```
   #define SWAP(a, b) ({ int tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp; })
   ```

   However it's strongly recommended to write it a function. If you worry about efficiency of function calls, just use the `inline` modifier.
2. Your algorithm logic seems not okay. To be specific, replace these lines:

   ```
   } while (!swapped);  /* in implementation 1 */
   } while (!n);        /* in implementation 2 */
   ```

   with

   ```
   } while (swapped);  /* in implementation 1 */
   } while (n);        /* in implementation 2 */
   ```

   The reason, is that you need to keep on swapping until there's no item swapped.

**EDITED:**
I'm explaining my example above using some detailed information.

First of all, I claimed that it's undefined behavior that:

> the sequence of fetching values from memory and also writing back to memory on statements like `a ^= b ^= c ^= d;`

because I didn't find related specifications in the standard(`ISO/IEC 9899:2011`). However if anyone finds some evidence that supports/opposes this, please let me know. :)

Now let's have some code. Below is the related parts of assembly generated by `gcc` for my code example:

```
# int a = 1;
# int b = 2;
# a ^= b ^= a ^= b;
movl    $1, -4(%rbp)    # initialize a
movl    $2, -8(%rbp)    # initialize b
movl    -8(%rbp), %eax  # loads b into eax
xorl    %eax, -4(%rbp)  # a ^= eax
movl    -4(%rbp), %eax  # loads a into eax
xorl    %eax, -8(%rbp)  # b ^= eax 
movl    -8(%rbp), %eax  # loads b into eax
xorl    %eax, -4(%rbp)  # a ^= eax

# int x[] = { 1, 2, };
# x[0] ^= x[1] ^= x[0] ^= x[1];
movl    $1, -16(%rbp)   # initialize x[0]
movl    $2, -12(%rbp)   # initialize x[1]
movl    -16(%rbp), %edx # loads x[0] into edx
movl    -12(%rbp), %ecx # loads x[1] into ecx
movl    -16(%rbp), %esi # loads x[0] into esi
movl    -12(%rbp), %eax # loads x[1] into eax
xorl    %esi, %eax      # eax = x[0] ^ x[1]
movl    %eax, -16(%rbp) # writes eax into x[0]
movl    -16(%rbp), %eax # loads (new)x[0] into eax
xorl    %ecx, %eax      # eax = x[1] ^ (new)x[0]
movl    %eax, -12(%rbp) # writes eax into x[1]
movl    -12(%rbp), %eax # loads (new)x[1] into eax
xorl    %edx, %eax      # eax = (new)x[1] ^ (old)x[0]
movl    %eax, -16(%rbp) # writes eax into x[0]
```

You could easily see the last but one line uses the old value of `x[0]`, which leads to the unexpected results.
I'm using `gcc 4.8.2`.

**EDITED:**
Also `#define SWAP(a, b) ({ a ^= b; b ^= a; a ^= b; })` is totally fine.

Comment: Thanks Starrify. I had known this trick for a while, but I fail to understand exactly why it fails. Is it because changing an array directly is undefined behaviour? thanks, I appreciate your time and making it more understandable for me :)

Comment: @user3043746 Changing an array shall be fine. I've updated the answer to explain exactly how the problem is introduced.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that `SWAP()` isn't working, since the data is corrupted.

I guess it's possible that `SWAP()` works fine, since both 0 and 22 occur in the input, though. Still, it's definitely a source of confusion and possible bugs and badness, so it should be the first thing you fix in this program. Just do a plain old ordinary swap with a temporary variable:

```
const int tmp = a[i - 1];
a[i - 1] = a[i];
a[i] = tmp;
```

That XOR trickery *might* be useful somewhere, but it's not here.

Comment: Those bit hacks originated back when doing things like that could gain some observable speed. Like on a Z80 chip.

Comment: @jimmcnamara I guess correctness shall be more important than performance. Also on one of my previous talks to students I discussed about low-level optimizations, and one thing I told them is, "you shall always understand exactly what the compiler does to your code before believing that you're smarter than the compiler".

Comment: @jimmcnamara BTW, one of my favorite teachers is also quite familiar with programming for Z80! He often tells us his experiences of programming that happens tens of years ago. :)